# jQuery object or div id string as a param?

Tags: jquery

Which is a better option,

to pass a string representing div id as a parameter to a function and in the function get the jQuery object using `$("#" + divid)` and update it

or

to pass the jQuery object itself as a parameter to the function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if we're up for considering the [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) OO principle, we should pass the object (i.e. inject the dependency), and let the function's code refer to the abstraction (the jQuery object interface). You'll also have saved some overhead from removing some string operations.

Otherwise, I'd not fret too much. The most important thing is to be consistent across your code base.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second, passing the object, to reduce the cost of fetching and initialing the object again.